# D3.js - Setting a minimum and maximum range for a drag event

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm using D3.js to create a draggable line chart, it works fine but I can't figure out how to set a minimum and maximum bound, at the moment if I have a dataset i.e [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3] dragging a series point will move into a number outside of the dataset range. I would like the bounds to be the min-max of my dataset, in this case, you can drag a data series between 2-12. Here's a link to a jsfiddle that demonstrates my issue https://jsfiddle.net/e8n4xd4z/1549/

```
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [
        {
          label: '# of Votes',
          data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderWidth: 1
        },  
            {
                label: '# of Points',
                data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
                borderWidth: 1
            }
        ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
                    reverse: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
var chartInstance = new Chart(ctx, options);

d3.select(chartInstance.chart.canvas).call(
  d3.drag().container(chartInstance.chart.canvas)
    .on('start', getElement)
    .on('drag', updateData)
    .on('end', callback)
);

var element, scale, datasetIndex, index, value


function getElement () {
    var e = d3.event.sourceEvent
    element = chartInstance.getElementAtEvent(e)[0]
  scale = element['_yScale'].id
}


function updateData () {
    var e = d3.event.sourceEvent
  datasetIndex = element['_datasetIndex']
  index = element['_index']
  value = chartInstance.scales[scale].getValueForPixel(e.clientY)
  chartInstance.data.datasets[datasetIndex].data[index] = value
  chartInstance.update(0)
}

function callback () {
 
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> in this case, you can drag a data series between 2-12

Should it be 2 - 19 since the max of data is 19?

When drag happens, `updateData` works and it get the `value` using `getValueForPixel`, then update the data and the chart.

```
chartInstance.data.datasets[datasetIndex].data[index] = value
```

So to limit the drag event in a [min, max], you should limit the data to update actually, make them between [min, max], then you will feel like that the drag event has bounds.

```
function updateData () {
  var e = d3.event.sourceEvent
  datasetIndex = element['_datasetIndex']
  index = element['_index']
  value = chartInstance.scales[scale].getValueForPixel(e.clientY)
  // limit the value that will be updated in the [min, max]
  value =  Math.min(19, Math.max(2, value))
  chartInstance.data.datasets[datasetIndex].data[index] = value
  chartInstance.update(0)
}
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mf6r7uy1/3/)